# Replace javascript não funciona de forma geral

Tags: javascript

Por que quando eu faço:

```
"1.000.000,00".replace('.','');
```

ele me retorna:

```
"1000.000,00"
```

Como faço para ele funcionar com todos os caractéres? que seria assim: `"1000000,00"`

Comment: Por que os três votos para reabrir? Mesmo após a edição, a solução é a mesma (usar uma expressão regular com a flag 'global'). Lembrem-se de que fechamento como duplicata não é uma coisa ruim. Na maioria dos casos, é bom manter no site múltiplas perguntas sobre o mesmo assunto, mas apontando para a mesma resposta. Isso aumenta a chance de se encontrar a resposta via mecanismos de buscas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um `replace` [global](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) com a opção, altere seu `replace`, para:

```
"SILVANO SILVADO".replace(/A/g,'@');
```

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2nnK/)**

#### Editado

Após edição da pergunta, segue a nova solução:

```
"1.000.000,00".replace(/\./g,'')
```

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2nnK/1/)**

Comment: Legal, sei que não coloquei na pergunta, mas e se for `1.000.000,00` ? eu posso fazer isso `"1.000.000,00".replace(/./g,'');` ? para remover todos os pontos?

Comment: Sim, você pode se usar um scape `"1.000.000,00".replace(/\./g,'')`, veja http://jsfiddle.net/R2nnK/1/

Comment: Amigo devido a umas complicações eu editei a pergunta, poderia por favor postar essa solução do comentário como resposta?

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, feito